# How to change Font Family and position of text on a Pie chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, fonts, pie-chart

I have pie chart below in R.
I wan to :
1- change the font family to let s say Arial Narrow.
2- move the inner chart percentage labels farther from the center.
How can I do this?

ALSO, if possible I would love to know what s the logic behind the order R opts for legend? why not from the largest proportion to the smallest?

```
mydf <- data.frame(
causes=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "other"),
freq=c(100, 80, 78, 75, 120),#
share= 100*c(100/sum(freq), 80/sum(freq), 78/sum(freq), 75/sum(freq), 120/sum(freq))
 )
sum(freq)
ggplot(mydf, aes("", share, fill = causes)) +



geom_bar(width = 1, size = 1, color = "white", stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(share), "%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size=5, col="white") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL, 
       title = "leading causes of death in US") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#003B6D", "#6699CC", "#BDBDBD", "#676767", "#EBEDF3")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "#666666"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
mydf$Label  <- round(((mydf$freq/sum(mydf$freq))*100),2)
mydf <- mydf %>%
  mutate(end = 2 * pi * cumsum(Label)/sum(Label),
         start = lag(end, default = 0),
         middle = 0.5 * (start + end),
         hjust = ifelse(middle > pi, 1, 0),
         vjust = ifelse(middle < pi/2 | middle > 3 * pi/2, 0, 1))


ggplot(mydf) + 
  ggforce::geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0, r = 1,
                   start = start, end = end, fill = causes)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.05 * sin(middle), y = 1.05 * cos(middle), label = Label,
                hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL, 
       title = "leading causes of death in US") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#003B6D", "#6699CC", "#BDBDBD", "#676767", "#EBEDF3")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "#666666"))
```

[image]

## Inside

```
mydf <- mydf %>%
  mutate(end = 2 * pi * cumsum(Label)/sum(Label),
         start = lag(end, default = 0),
         middle = 0.5 * (start + end),
         hjust = ifelse(middle > pi, 0, 1),
         vjust = ifelse(middle < pi/2 | middle > 3 * pi/2, 1, 0))


ggplot(mydf) + 
  ggforce::geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0, r = 1,
                            start = start, end = end, fill = causes)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0.95 * sin(middle), y = 0.95 * cos(middle), label = Label,
                hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL, 
       title = "leading causes of death in US") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#003B6D", "#6699CC", "#BDBDBD", "#676767", "#EBEDF3")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "#666666"))
```

[image]

## font

```
ggplot(mydf) + 
  ggforce::geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0, r = 1,
                            start = start, end = end, fill = causes)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0.95 * sin(middle), y = 0.95 * cos(middle), label = Label,
                hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust), fontface = "bold") + #inside chart here
  coord_fixed() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL, 
       title = "leading causes of death in US") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#003B6D", "#6699CC", "#BDBDBD", "#676767", "#EBEDF3")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "#666666"),
        text = element_text(family = "sans")) #title here
```

for `fontface`, "plain", "bold", "italic", "bold.italic" are available and for `element_text(family)`, mono

```
sans
serif
Courier
Helvetica
Times
AvantGarde
Bookman
Helvetica-Narrow
NewCenturySchoolbook
Palatino
URWGothic
URWBookman
NimbusMon
URWHelvetica
NimbusSan
NimbusSanCond
CenturySch
URWPalladio
URWTimes
NimbusRom
```

are available.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I ve been playing with what you suggested to maybe get what I wanted . I noticed changing  hjust = ifelse(middle > pi, 1, 0) to  hjust = ifelse(middle > pi, -2, 0),  makes the label 26.49 move inside but close to the circumference of circle ( what I want for ALL the labels ). but how can I move ALL the labels inside but close to the circumference.

Comment: @Mathica Well, it would be better to just flip `ifelse` statements for `hjust` and `vjust`. Then, change coefficients that multiplied for location of text from `1.05` to `0.95` will make labels inside. I add code and plot above.

Comment: PERFECT! thank you. any idea you to change the font family of labels on pie chart in ggplot?

Comment: @Mathica I'm really sorry. I completely forgot about font questions. I add font-about arguments above. Please check it out.